# Word with special character (cedilla) not hyphenated

Tags: fonts, hyphenation, languages

I am trying to understand why the last word in the first line is not hyphenated:

[image]

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headsep=14pt, paperwidth=14cm, paperheight=21cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.75cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
%\hyphenation{es-pe-ran-ça} % Throws error

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
Mmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmm.
Mmmmmm mm esperança.
Mmm mmm mmm mmmm mm mmmm mmm mmm mmm mmm mmm mmmm
Mmm mmm mmm mmmm mm mmmm mmm mmm mm mmmm mmmm mmm
Mmm mmm mmm mmmm mm mmmm mmm mmm mmm mmm mmm mmmm
mmm mmm mmmm mmmmmmm.\par
\end{document}
```

Looks like an issue with the Charter typeface? All the other lines right alignment are a little messed up too. Compare with another font:

[image]

Compiled with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Switch to T1 encoding, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`